# Proper way of choosing hubs

Tags: hub

Not a product rec question, I mostly need to know the way of selecting the correct hubs for me.

I've got a GT Avalanche 9R expert and I'm not happy with it's hubs.

1. I use this bike only for xcm and other off-road riding - as I understand I need to have a hub with industrial bearings (not sure if it's the correct word) - right? What difference makes the number of them? (Some have 2, some 4)
2. (A bit more specific one) That's what I've found in specs:

   [image]

Should I look only for QR models of I can use 10mm through axle?

3. Now I have a center-lock rotor mount. Is it interchangeable with 6-bolt?

Comment: Can you say why you are not happy with the hubs? Are the bearings worn out? You should be able to have a bike store replace the bearings if you want to keep the wheels. It might be as economical to find replacement wheels instead of searching for hubs and then lacing them to your old rims.

Comment: The old ones are cone and cup and not sealed at all - so I have to service them way more than I'd like to. It's really wet where I live, so trails are often covered with wet dirt which is bad for those hubs. Replacing wheels might be a good idea, but there are hubs in them - which leads me to the same question of how to I choose them)

Comment: Unless there's something wrong with the hubs you have, you almost certainly wouldn't be able to notice any change if they were replaced with the lightest, most expensive high-end hubs you could buy.  The power lost in the cheapest, worst wheel bearings is already extremely small compared to the total power needed to ride the replacing cheap bearings with the best, lowest-friction bearings ever mode won't really change a thing.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes, unless. And this is just a matter of one not too long (~50km) ride in wet and dirty conditions

Comment: Ok.  But read this on "sealed" bearings:  https://www.sheldonbrown.com/brandt/sealed-bearings.html

Comment: Thanks. So... Is there any way to have a hub that needs less maintenance or at least less often? On the other bike I have funn am, and it seems to perform better, though it's now used mostly in the city

Comment: The article that @AndrewHenle cited was written in the late 1990s. Since then, I have heard that Phil Wood cartridge bearings have relatively good seals, and that they should be more resistant to contamination. I haven't investigated personally. Phil does make cartridge bearings in standard sizes, so they could be retrofitted to most hubs that take cartridge bearings. I'm not personally aware of other brands that might make hubs with good seals that are designed for frequent wet rides.

Answer (score 3):

If you are having to service hubs after a 50km ride in wet and muddy conditions something is wrong. All bearings on modern hubs are 'sealed'; not hermetically, but enough to prevent ingress of water and dirt and should not need servicing so often.

Just to address you other questions:

Re 'industrial bearings' I think you mean cartridge bearing types (which use industrial standards for sizes and quality). You don't need these per se. Cup and cone bearings work fine.

You cannot use through-axles on a frame designed for quick release axles. Some hubs are convertible from TA to QR though.

Center lock and 6-bolt rotors are not interchangeable.

With inexpensive wheels it's not cost effective to replace hubs because new hub, new spokes and the cost of rebuilding the wheel is comparable to the cost of a whole wheel.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding rotors - I've meant can I use 6 bolt hubs with new rotors and same brake calipers mount? In other words - will the rotor be in the same place?

Comment: A minor point of info: there are adaptors that can take a 6-bolt rotor and fit it to a center lock hub (Google if interested). I believe the reverse don't exist. @k102, the rotors should be in roughly the same place between the two, but you would need to stick to the same hub to get them in exactly the same place.